# View controller isn't filling up screen Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

My view controller was set up without auto layout, and now for some reason it only fills the whole screen in iPhone 5's. I need auto layout off, and for it to fill the screen in all iPhone models. What it shows on Xcode and iPhone 5 is

[image: this]

but what it shows in the simulator for example, an iPhone 6 simulator, is

[image: this]

But for some reason I can't change the constraints. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to set constraints for each item in your view.

Comment: @J.Lopes Read last sentance.

Comment: Why don't you can change the constraints? I mean, what is it happening?

Comment: @Sam "I need auto layout off, and for it to fill the screen in all iPhone models." - Any reason for this? If you're disabling autolayout, then you're going to have to perform manual calculation of all of the view sizes.

Comment: @Kamaros it would really mess up if i didn't. don't know why.

Comment: @J.Lopes t would really mess up if i didn't. don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean "it would really mess up"? I get it, you have disabled the auto layout. I think you should try use auto layuot, but if it's not possible you will need to set all your views programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `Reset to Suggested Constraints` and see what happens:

[image]

You can read more about auto constraints here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

I hope this can help you.

Comment: The little 4 icons down there are gone, forgot to mention.

Comment: @Sam Could you post a screenshot of what the bottom of your IB looks like, demonstrating the missing icons?

Comment: whether i select an item in the  view controller or not, it doesn't show up. Ive tried from the editor, but that doesn't allow me to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the constraints and putting them back?

Answer (score 0):

If you removed auto layout you need to set it manually, but the right one is to use auto layout, let the historical method away.